# Empty WhenEvent action crashes kernel

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, crash

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

*`WhenEvent` is new in 9.0.*

---

This is an example from the docs, slightly modified (action is wrapped in `{ }`), working as expected.

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, {x[t] -> x[t] + (-1)^t}]}, x, {t, 0, 3}]
```

> ```
>   {{x -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 3.}}, <>]}}
> ```

When the action is deliberately removed (because for example the action is programmatically generated for a list of variables that can be empty), it crashes the kernel.

**Warning: the following line might crash the kernel. Save your work.**

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, 
  WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, {(*x[t] -> x[t] + (-1)^t*)}]}, x, {t, 0, 3}]
```

Can anyone reproduce this?

(*Mathematica* 10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (Win7, 64-bit))

Comment: Confirmed on OS X 10.11.4, M 10.4.1, M 10.3.1, M 10.0.2 and M 9.0.1.  All of them crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Szabolcs, submitting to TechSupport. I've found more bugs in the last month than in the last 10 years of using Mathematica. It's like crossing a threshold after which one cannot really be productive due to seeing bugs everyewhere. They are swarming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TechSupport acknowledged and proposed a simple workaround by putting inert expression, e.g. empty string, inside the `{ }`:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, {""}]}, x, {t, 0, 3}]
```